# I have problem with multi companies flow when confirm order Odoo 15

Tags: odoo

I have a multi companies flow where Purchase Order from Company A will create Sale Order for Company B, I am trying to automatically confirm that Sale Order. Each Company has different flow when confirm Sale Order.

I am running the code with OdooBot because I need access to both Companies, but when confirm Sale Order for company B, it always trigger the flow of confirming order of company A, I dont know why.

If I choose both companies on the top right multi-company widget and then confirm the SO, the same problem happens.

If I only choose company B on the top right multi-company widget and then confirm the SO, it will work fine.

How am I gonna simulate this behavior by code? I tried with_company and with_context(allowed_company_ids), nothing worked

so_res.with_company(so_res.company_id).action_confirm()
It still triggers the flow of company A

Comment: Flow starts from order company. Ensure order is being created from the correct company